# React Native Expo AV - Audio not playing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-av

I am implementing an AudioPlayer using the [expo-av](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/) library. For playing audios I am doing this:

```
import { Audio } from "expo-av";

export default function AudioPlayer() {}

AudioPlayer.playSound = async function (
  source,
  initialStatus = { shouldPlay: true },
  onPlaybackStatusUpdate = null,
  downloadFirst = true
) {
  try {
    // Create a complete sound object
    const { sound, status } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
      source,
      initialStatus,
      onPlaybackStatusUpdate,
      downloadFirst
    );

    console.log(status);

    // Play the sound
    await sound.playAsync();

    console.log("Sound played! Unloading from memory...");

    // We are done...
    // Unload the sound from memory
    sound.unloadAsync();
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};
```

But, for some reason, when I do

```
AudioPlayer.playSound(require("../../assets/microphone-button-press.mp3"));
```

no sound is played.

What am I doing wrong? (tested on iPhone 11 pro, iOS 14)

This is how the status object I am logging looks like:

```
Object {
  "didJustFinish": false,
  "durationMillis": 3120,
  "hasJustBeenInterrupted": false,
  "isBuffering": false,
  "isLoaded": true,  <---------------
  "isLooping": false,
  "isMuted": false, <------------
  "isPlaying": false,
  "pitchCorrectionQuality": "Varispeed",
  "playableDurationMillis": 3120,
  "positionMillis": 0,
  "progressUpdateIntervalMillis": 500,
  "rate": 1,
  "shouldCorrectPitch": false,
  "shouldPlay": true, <-----------------
  "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E249E9F5-63EE-4421-88E6-F4F52B0D99F2/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540victorio%252Fmy-app-name/ExponentAsset-cd2511ab9f64faf7c2c23a26c8ac58c5.mp3", <----------------
  "volume": 1, <--------------
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are unloading the audio right after  the playAsync call. Is it normal ?

Comment: I saw it in the docs. But I changed it and now working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Load your sound before playing it.

```
await sound.current.loadAsync(
      Sounds[audioSourceWithRequire],
    );

then await sound.current.playAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I little bit old but in case some one get into this at 2023/2024 for newer versions. the solution posted  [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/14291) solved for me.

```
await _sound.loadAsync(require("./assets/sounds/sample.mp3"), {shouldPlay: true});
```